Can't get attribute 'ConvWrapper' on <module 'yolov6.layers.common'
!git clone https://github.com/meituan/YOLOv6.git
%cd YOLOv6
import cv2
import torch
import pyttsx3
import warnings
warnings.filterwarnings("ignore")
class currency_detection:
def _init_(self, path):
self.model = torch.hub.load('meituan/YOLOv6', 'yolov6l', force_reload=True)
self.engine = pyttsx3.init()
I am trying to do detect with yolov6 in jupyter notebook. but some attribute error is throwing.this is the error:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[3], line 3
      1 vidpath = r"C:\Users\sajja\Desktop\ZUMMIT\Spharva\prj-third-eye-main-currency_identification\currency_identification\data\all_test_videos.mp4"
----> 3 currency = currency_detection(r"C:\Users\sajja\Desktop\ZUMMIT\Spharva\prj-third-eye-main-currency_identification\currency_identification\YOLOv6\yolov6l.pt")
      4 currency.main_detection(videopath=vidpath)

Cell In[2], line 13, in currency_detection.__init__(self, path)
     11 def __init__(self, path):
---> 13     self.model = torch.hub.load('meituan/YOLOv6', 'yolov6l', force_reload=True)
     14     self.engine = pyttsx3.init()

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:568, in load(repo_or_dir, model, source, trust_repo, force_reload, verbose, skip_validation, *args, **kwargs)
    564 if source == 'github':
    565     repo_or_dir = _get_cache_or_reload(repo_or_dir, force_reload, trust_repo, "load",
    566                                        verbose=verbose, skip_validation=skip_validation)
--> 568 model = _load_local(repo_or_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    569 return model

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:597, in _load_local(hubconf_dir, model, *args, **kwargs)
    594     hub_module = _import_module(MODULE_HUBCONF, hubconf_path)
    596     entry = _load_entry_from_hubconf(hub_module, model)
--> 597     model = entry(*args, **kwargs)
    599 return model

File ~/.cache\torch\hub\meituan_YOLOv6_main\hubconf.py:176, in yolov6l(class_names, device, img_size, conf_thres, iou_thres, max_det)
    175 def yolov6l(class_names=CLASS_NAMES, device=DEVICE, img_size=640, conf_thres=0.25, iou_thres=0.45, max_det=1000):
--> 176     return create_model('yolov6l', class_names, device, img_size=img_size, conf_thres=conf_thres,
    177                         iou_thres=iou_thres, max_det=max_det)

File ~/.cache\torch\hub\meituan_YOLOv6_main\hubconf.py:152, in create_model(model_name, class_names, device, img_size, conf_thres, iou_thres, max_det)
    150     os.mkdir(str(PATH_YOLOv6/'weights'))
    151 if not os.path.exists(str(PATH_YOLOv6/'weights') + f'/{model_name}.pt'):
--> 152     torch.hub.load_state_dict_from_url(
    153         f"https://github.com/meituan/YOLOv6/releases/download/0.3.0/{model_name}.pt",
    154         str(PATH_YOLOv6/'weights'))
    155 return Detector(str(PATH_YOLOv6/'weights') + f'/{model_name}.pt',
    156                 class_names, device, img_size=img_size, conf_thres=conf_thres,
    157                 iou_thres=iou_thres, max_det=max_det)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\hub.py:764, in load_state_dict_from_url(url, model_dir, map_location, progress, check_hash, file_name, weights_only)
    762 if _is_legacy_zip_format(cached_file):
    763     return _legacy_zip_load(cached_file, model_dir, map_location, weights_only)
--> 764 return torch.load(cached_file, map_location=map_location, weights_only=weights_only)

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1025, in load(f, map_location, pickle_module, weights_only, mmap, **pickle_load_args)
   1023             except RuntimeError as e:
   1024                 raise pickle.UnpicklingError(UNSAFE_MESSAGE + str(e)) from None
-> 1025         return _load(opened_zipfile,
   1026                      map_location,
   1027                      pickle_module,
   1028                      overall_storage=overall_storage,
   1029                      **pickle_load_args)
   1030 if mmap:
   1031     f_name = "" if not isinstance(f, str) else f"{f}, "

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1446, in _load(zip_file, map_location, pickle_module, pickle_file, overall_storage, **pickle_load_args)
   1444 unpickler = UnpicklerWrapper(data_file, **pickle_load_args)
   1445 unpickler.persistent_load = persistent_load
-> 1446 result = unpickler.load()
   1448 torch._utils._validate_loaded_sparse_tensors()
   1449 torch._C._log_api_usage_metadata(
   1450     "torch.load.metadata", {"serialization_id": zip_file.serialization_id()}
   1451 )

File ~\anaconda3\Lib\site-packages\torch\serialization.py:1439, in _load.<locals>.UnpicklerWrapper.find_class(self, mod_name, name)
   1437         pass
   1438 mod_name = load_module_mapping.get(mod_name, mod_name)
-> 1439 return super().find_class(mod_name, name)

AttributeError: Can't get attribute 'ConvWrapper' on <module 'yolov6.layers.common' from 'C:\\Users\\sajja/.cache\\torch\\hub\\meituan_YOLOv6_main\\yolov6\\layers\\common.py'>

i tried re instaling requiremnet.txt but still the same error.
